# sum specific cells with a condition - vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to sum the numbers from E column for each name and put the result in column F. I mean:

*(Sheet1)*

> ```
>      colA-Name:   colE-Number:       
> row1: Michael          16         
> row2: Michael          20         
> row3: Andrew           15         
> row4: Edward           19         
> row5: Edward           13         
> row6: Edward           24         
> row7: Helen            17
> ```

And I want something like this:

> ```
>      colA-Name:   colF-SUM:       
> row1: Michael          36         
> row2: Michael                    
> row3: Andrew           15         
> row4: Edward           56         
> row5: Edward                       
> row6: Edward                   
> row7: Helen            17
> ```

Here is my code so far but doesn't work.

```
    Sub sum()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim lastRowA As Long
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myString As String

    lastRowA = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRowA)
    Set cel = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")

    'find duplicates name in column A
    Set myRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRowA).Find(What:=myString, LookAt:=xlPart)

    For Each cel In Rng
        'if founded, sum their numbers and put it in F column    
        If Not myRange Is Nothing Then
             cel.Offset(0, 5) = cel.Offset(0, 4).Value + cel.Offset(1, 4).Value 
            'Range("F:F").Value = cel.Offset(0, 4).Value + cel.Offset(1, 4).Value
        End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

Is anyone able to help? Thanks!

Comment: `but doesn't work` What **exactly** doesn't work? Are you getting errors, or unexpected ouput(s)? Can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25402657/edit) your question and add more detail?

Comment: @RossC : doesn't do anything...no result.

Comment: But when you go through it with the debugger, where is it missing the functionality you require? Can you narrow down your problem? I'm asking to help you learn this. Is your range correct firstly? Are you finding 'Each cel in Range' etc...

Comment: Did you check what is myString?

Comment: I don't know what is missing. Personally, I think my code is ok but I don't know why I have no result. When I go through it with the debugger, I have no errors. It loops n times this code: 'If Not myRange Is Nothing Then cel.Offset(0, 5) = cel.Offset(0, 4).Value + cel.Offset(1, 4).Value 'Range("F:F").Value = cel.Offset(0, 4).Value + cel.Offset(1, 4).Value End If'

Comment: myString contains multiple texts in column A. Why should I check?

Comment: @musiclandia, does it now? Have you checked it? I cannot see where it is being assigned that value.

Comment: no. I think myString shouldn't be assigned because that variable always changing.

Comment: Why should I check it? I'm sorry but I don't understand. What value should I assign to myString?

Comment: @musiclandia  In your inital line, you write *I want to sum the numbers from F column for each name and put the result in column E.*  Is that a correct statement?  Or do you have it reversed?  If correct, then you are dividing the values in col F to get the results in Col E using an unspecified algorithm.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld : Yes, is correct the statement. For every name I want to sum the numbers. You can understand better in the example. What should I change in my code? I don't understand. I'm not dividing the values but I get the results in col F (cel.Offset(0, 5) =...). Where did you see that?

Comment: @musiclandia In your post, you write that you want to ** put the result in column E**.  Yet it seems you do not want the results in Column E but rather in Column F

Comment: @musiclandia You seem to think that you don't need to assign anything to MyString.  But the fact that MyString is nothing is why your MyRange variable will always be nothing; hence your macro won't do anything.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld you're right. I want to put the results in column F. Sorry. Give me an advice how to do that, please.... what value should take mystring?

Comment: @musiclandia *YOU* wrote code which uses MyString as an argument. You must have had something in mind.  Whatever that was is what you should be using.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld :I solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple excel formula for the job if that may suit

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(ACurRow;A$1:A(CurRow-1);1;FALSE));SUMIF(A$1:A$LastRow;ACurRow;E$1:E$LastRow);"")
```

- Enter the formula in your expected results column on any row - except the first one. This is the row I am referring to as "CurRow"
- replace the "CurRow" and "LastRow" references to your actual values in the formula
- paste the formula in all other rows

Comment: Thanks, but I should create a new Worksheet from another and do different functions in it. I can't use formula. Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I have changed the way but is what I want. The code below:

- find duplicates name from column A
- copy once each name in column F
- calculate the sum of the numbers matched to each name.
- I get the results in column G.

The code:

```
    Sub sum()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim myString As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Found As Boolean

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Select
    lastrRowA = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("F2:G" & lastrRowA).Clear
    Set rngA = ws.Range("A2:A" & lastrRowA)

    'find duplicates in column A and copy once in column F
    For Each cell In rngA
        myString = cell.Value
        i = 2
        Found = False
        While ws.Cells(i, 6).Value <> "" And Not Found
            If ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = myString Then
                Found = True
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Wend
        If Not Found Then
            ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = myString
        End If
    Next

    'ascending column F
    ws.Select
        ws.Range("F2:F" & lastrRowA).Select
        Selection.sort Key1:=Range("F1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
            ws.Range("A1").Select

 'sum the numbers(from column E) for each Name (i.e. Michael=16+20=36 etc.) and put the results in col G
    For RRF = 1 To ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    NT = ws.Range("F" & RRF).Value
        For RR1 = 1 To lastrRowA
        If NT = ws.Range("A" & RR1).Value Then ws.Range("G" & RRF).Value = ws.Range("G" & RRF).Value + ws.Range("E" & RR1).Value
        Next RR1
    Next RRF

    End Sub
```